# Drag and Drop: Trying to understand DropDemo tutorial

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop

I'm working on Drag and Drop right now, and I've found an interesting tutorial on Oracle's website on custom TransferHandlers, etc. etc. etc. Anyway, I've been staring at the source code for the custom handler in the DropDemo program they provide, and it's driving me crazy.

What's confusing me is that there appear to be a whole bunch of methods that aren't invoked: importData(), importString(), and exportDone(). They all appear to serve vital functions, and all must be triggered at some point, but I can't seem to see where in the program these methods are being called.

I'm ultimately trying to understand how DropDemo offers the ability to re-order a JList through drag and drop, since I have so far been unable to replicate this. However, this has morphed into my larger question.

Answer (score 1):

[`Transferable#importData(TransferHandler.TransferSupport)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/TransferHandler.html#importData(javax.swing.TransferHandler.TransferSupport))

> Causes a transfer to occur from a clipboard or a drag and drop
>   operation. The Transferable to be imported and the component to
>   transfer to are contained within the TransferSupport.
>  While the drag
>   and drop implementation calls canImport to determine the suitability
>   of a transfer before calling this method, the implementation of paste
>   does not. As such, it cannot be assumed that the transfer is
>   acceptable upon a call to this method for paste. It is recommended
>   that canImport be explicitly called to cover this case.
>
> Note: The TransferSupport object passed to this method is only valid
>   for the duration of the method call. It is undefined what values it
>   may contain after this method returns.

Basically, this is called when the component which the `Transferable` is associated it detects an "import" event.  This is the opportunity for the `Transferable` to physically import the data from the `TransferHandler.TransferSupport` based on it's requirements

[`Transferable#exportDone`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/TransferHandler.html#exportDone(javax.swing.JComponent,%20java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable,%20int))

> Invoked after data has been exported. This method should remove the
>   data that was transferred if the action was MOVE.
>  This method is
>   implemented to do nothing since MOVE is not a supported action of this
>   implementation (getSourceActions does not include MOVE).

This is called on the instance of `Transferable` which initiated the export process, telling it what action was taken by the receiver of the transfer so it can take appropriate action

It should be noted that not all the methods have to be called, for example, if you're exporting the data, then you would not be notified of the `importData` method.  Equally, if the transfer it is never completed successfully, then `exportDone` may not be called.

These methods are triggered by core D'n'D subsystem, ontop of which the `Transferable` API sits and are done in response to lower level events.  You don't really need to "know" how they are called, but need to know what to do "when" they are called.  This is a bit more of the "black magic" of event driven program.

> I'm ultimately trying to understand how DropDemo offers the ability to re-order a JList through drag and drop, since I have so far been unable to replicate this. However, this has morphed into my larger question. So thanks in advance.

[For example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26288671/move-and-reorder-jlabels-in-jpanel-using-dnd/26289614#26289614)

Comment: Done... However, not to be pedantic, but the question isn't an answer. Your answer will still get picked up. Moving on.